# data table alternative to relist function R

Tags: r, list, data.table

I am looking for a faster, data table alternative to the `relist` function, specifically the `skeleton` argument that allows you to group values based on a specific structure. I know the `by` option does this for you but that's only by columns in the data table. I want to ultimately take a column of values from a data table and group those values based on an already created 'frame' for the values. For example, the code below shows how `listFrame` is created and would be passed to the `skeleton` argument to group values based on each sequence of numbers.

```
library(data.table)

sampleData <- data.table(rep(seq(0,10), each = 10))
sampleData <- sampleData[-(sample(1:length(sampleData[[1]]), 25))]
nList <- as.data.table(sampleData[, table(V1)])

listFrame <- data.table(sapply(1:nrow(nList), function(x) 1:nList$N[x]))
sampleData <- relist(sampleData[[1]], listFrame[[1]])
```

Furthermore, after relisting `sampleData` I plan to apply a function over each sublist, using `lapply`. If it can all be done using `data.table` that would be great.

```
lapply(1:length(sampleData), function(x) median(sampleData[[x]]))
```

Comment: I really do not get it why you need all this relisting. You could add a group id column to your existing data table which represents 'frame' as you call it `dt[, id := ...]` and then apply function over every group `dt[, ..., by = id]`.

Comment: See the weird thing is, I tried that. The `lapply` that calls the `median` function on each sublist produces values and then I take the mean of those. The method you described and the `lapply` should return the same values but they aren't. I did exactly how you described. So I just assumed there was another way. @danas.zuokas

Comment: To be specific, I'm taking a huge data set and grouping them by their 'ID' then applying the `tbrm` function from the `dplR` package and then taking the mean of those values. The two different methods should return the same values.

Comment: Can you post what you tried with the data.table way? 
something like `DT[, .(mean(dplR::tbrm(col))), by = ID]` should work ?

Comment: That's exactly right except that you have to take the mean after you call the `tbrm` function. So no need to call `mean` within the data table because I want the mean of the values generated from `tbrm`. It should work, and so I tried it before posting but my values were different. I'm going to try something else and see what I get. @Titolondon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, your `listFrame` as skeleton is a way of counting same number in `V1`. As your input data is sorted on `V1`, I think is the same as a run-length type group id you could obtain with function `rleid`.

So you could group by `rleid(V1)` then apply the `median`

```r
library(data.table)

sampleData <- data.table(rep(seq(0,10), each = 10))
sampleData <- sampleData[-(sample(1:length(sampleData[[1]]), 25))]

sampleData[, .(med = median(V1)), by = .(V1, rleid(V1))][, rleid := NULL][]
#>     V1 med
#>  1:  0   0
#>  2:  1   1
#>  3:  2   2
#>  4:  3   3
#>  5:  4   4
#>  6:  5   5
#>  7:  6   6
#>  8:  7   7
#>  9:  8   8
#> 10:  9   9
#> 11: 10  10
```

Results in column `med` is the same as your example, but stored in a table not a list.

**After precision in comments**

`rleid` is a way for creating the ID column. If I take your specific case of function `dplR::tbrm`, you just need an ID column to apply the function.

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplR)

sampleData <- data.table(rep(seq(0,10), each = 10))
sampleData <- sampleData[-(sample(1:length(sampleData[[1]]), 25))]
```

create an ID column :

```
sampleData[, ID := LETTERS[rleid(V1)]]
```

Apply your function by `ID`

```
sampleData[, dplR::tbrm(V1), by = ID]
#>     ID V1
#>  1:  A  0
#>  2:  B  1
#>  3:  C  2
#>  4:  D  3
#>  5:  E  4
#>  6:  F  5
#>  7:  G  6
#>  8:  H  7
#>  9:  I  8
#> 10:  J  9
#> 11:  K 10
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, never heard of `rleid`.